# Como puedo mandar un mensaje al hacer click en un boton disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

no puedo mostrar el mensaje de alerta al hacer click en la opcion deshabilitada. Ya intente varias formas con onclick, click, attr pero no funcionan.

No se si hay otra forma de solucionarlo o no se sino sea con el id sino con la clase.

La libreria que utilizo es Select2 para crear el combobox multiple.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   //select2 dropdown
   $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
    var indiceOpcionBloqueada = 1;
    var indiceOpcionBloqueada2 = 2;

    //  seleciona la opción del indiceOpcionBloqueada
 $("#cars").find("option").eq(indiceOpcionBloqueada).prop("selected", true);
 $("#cars").find("option").eq(indiceOpcionBloqueada2).prop("selected", true);

// Deshabilita la opción del indiceOpcionBloqueada
 $("#cars").find("option").eq(indiceOpcionBloqueada).prop("disabled", true);
 $("#cars").find("option").eq(indiceOpcionBloqueada2).prop("disabled", true);
    
    // Deshabilita el boton de x del opción en Select2
    $("#cars").select2({
            templateSelection: function (data, container) {
                // Verifica si la opción está deshabilitada
                if (data.disabled) {
                    // Deshabilita el botón de eliminación (x)
                    $(container).find(".select2-selection__choice__remove").addClass("disabled");
                }
                return data.text;
            }
        });
        
     //Boton click para mostrar mensaje   
     $(".select2-selection__choice__remove").on("click", function(){
   alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
});
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select name="cars" id="cars" class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple>
    <option value="1">Volvo</option>
    <option value="2">Saab</option>
    <option value="3">Opel</option>
    <option value="4">Audi</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya logre mostrar el mensaje pero solo a una opcion seleccionada al darle click en la x, pero al darle click de nuevo a otra opcion seleccionada no funciona.

Comment: Cual sería ese botón, la `X` ??

Comment: @Yussef el boton x esta a la par de la opcion seleccionada

Comment: Es que no entiendo, donde hay que presionar ??

Comment: No sé entiende bien el problema que estás proponiendo. Da a entender o por lo menos así me lo ha parecido que cuando pulsas en la opción que ya está deshabilitada del desplegable te debería de aparecer el alert, pero no, es cuando pulsas la X de la opción seleccionada

Comment: por defecto te aparecen las opciones Saab y Opel deshabilitadas y si pulsas en la X te aparece un alert y te quita la opción, pero si vuelves a pulsar en el desplegable ves que la opción sigue deshabilitada

Comment: Entiendo que el select2 te muestra las opciones deshabilitadas por defecto y que tu las puedes quitar de ese "por defecto" y ya no volver a añadirlas y tu problema es que al añadir nuevas opciones, que por defecto no están deshabilitadas, no se deshabilitan en el select2 una vez las has seleccionado. ¿Sería algo así?

Comment: @JaimeGarcía lo que quiero ahorita es mostrar el mensaje de alerta al darle click en la x a una segunda opcion seleccionada que esta por defecto. Yo tengo la funciona de deshabilitar el boton de x entonces las personas no lo pueden quitar, aqui no funciona pero en el codigo mio si.

Comment: Ah vale. Ya te entiendo.
Solo te funciona una vez porque así se indica en el código, es decir, una vez pulsas el on click se hace una vez y el código termina porque al final va leyendo de manera secuencial. La solución sería hacer un for que recorra todas las opciones por defecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguramente lo que pasa es que `Select2` redibuja todo el control, entonces se pierden los eventos. Una forma seria agregarlos cada vez que hay un cambio usando el evento `change`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   //select2 dropdown
   $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
    var indiceOpcionBloqueada = 1;
    var indiceOpcionBloqueada2 = 2;

    //  seleciona la opción del indiceOpcionBloqueada
 $("#cars").find("option").eq(indiceOpcionBloqueada).prop("selected", true);
 $("#cars").find("option").eq(indiceOpcionBloqueada2).prop("selected", true);

// Deshabilita la opción del indiceOpcionBloqueada
 $("#cars").find("option").eq(indiceOpcionBloqueada).prop("disabled", true);
 $("#cars").find("option").eq(indiceOpcionBloqueada2).prop("disabled", true);
    
    // Deshabilita el boton de x del opción en Select2
  $("#cars").select2({
          templateSelection: function (data, container) {
              // Verifica si la opción está deshabilitada
              if (data.disabled) {
                  // Deshabilita el botón de eliminación (x)
                  $(container).find(".select2-selection__choice__remove").addClass("disabled");
              }
              return data.text;
          }
    });
    
    $('#cars').on('change', agregarAlerta);    
    agregarAlerta();
});

function agregarAlerta(){
 $(".select2-selection__choice__remove").on("click", function(){
   alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
 });
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select name="cars" id="cars" class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple>
    <option value="1">Volvo</option>
    <option value="2">Saab</option>
    <option value="3">Opel</option>
    <option value="4">Audi</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Una mejor forma sería usar el evento `select2:unselecting` y retornar `false` para parar el asunto

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   //select2 dropdown
   $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
    var indiceOpcionBloqueada = 1;
    var indiceOpcionBloqueada2 = 2;

    //  seleciona la opción del indiceOpcionBloqueada
 $("#cars").find("option").eq(indiceOpcionBloqueada).prop("selected", true);
 $("#cars").find("option").eq(indiceOpcionBloqueada2).prop("selected", true);

// Deshabilita la opción del indiceOpcionBloqueada
 $("#cars").find("option").eq(indiceOpcionBloqueada).prop("disabled", true);
 $("#cars").find("option").eq(indiceOpcionBloqueada2).prop("disabled", true);
    
    // Deshabilita el boton de x del opción en Select2
    $("#cars").select2({
            templateSelection: function (data, container) {
                // Verifica si la opción está deshabilitada
                if (data.disabled) {
                    // Deshabilita el botón de eliminación (x)
                    $(container).find(".select2-selection__choice__remove").addClass("disabled");
                }
                return data.text;
            }
        });
        
    $('#cars').on('select2:unselecting', agregarAlerta);   
});


function agregarAlerta(){
  alert("Una alerta");

 
 return false;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select name="cars" id="cars" class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple>
    <option value="1">Volvo</option>
    <option value="2">Saab</option>
    <option value="3">Opel</option>
    <option value="4">Audi</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias era la segunda opcion la que ocupaba y me funciona genial